# Dataframe with a Factor that has More Levels than Observations in R

Tags: r

Weird problem.

How can I have a dataframe that has more levels in a factor variable than there are observations?

```
> str(cash.SR)
'data.frame':   50 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ state     : Factor w/ 55 levels "Alabama","Alaska",..: 1 45 46 15 12 36 4 44 18 55 ...
 $ cash_avail: int  14909657 11401584 5900970 5760263 5612664 5466801 5435156 4850103 4415570 3459859 ...
```

This is nothing complicated.  I have a df with 2 columns and 50 rows (one corresponding to each state).

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to get rid of the extra levels or do you just want to know why `factor("Alaska", levels = state.name)` works?  I imagine you subsetted the rows at some point?  Anyway, `droplevels(cash.SR)` will drop unused levels

Comment: I'm just puzzled how I can have 55 levels for 50 states.  if I do dims(cash.SR) I get 50 x 2.  If I inspect the df using View(cash.SR) it shows me 2 columns of 50 observations.  How do I get 55?  Oh - and I didn't subset but did some groupby operations.

Comment: That  can't  be answered unless we see where the original data came from.  Obviously there are only 50 states, so I agree it's weird. Check the difference between the levels and the unique vector values

Comment: It's very easy to create factors with more levels than values: `factor(1, levels=1:3)`. If you subset from a factor variable with 55 levels and only get 50 hits there is no automatic shrinkage in the length of levels. You need to use `drop.levels` to return a factor object with fewer levels.

Comment: @42 That explains it!  I started with more levels (like "Samoa", etc) using the data and dropped those off.  So from what you are saying the df still recognizes 55 levels in the state factor because there is no automatic drop off. Got it!  Thx guys.

Comment: @42-: Your comment should be promoted to answer so that this question can be marked solved, eventually.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to create factors with more levels than values:

```
 tfac <- factor(1, levels=1:3)
 dput(tfac)
     #structure(1L, .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor")
```

If you subset from a factor variable with 55 levels and only get 50 hits there is no automatic shrinkage in the length of levels. You need to use drop.levels to return a factor object with fewer levels.